# ArcGIS Android - Get LatLon position of the graphic

Tags: arcgis-android

I'm adding marker to my map using the following code:

```
mvHelper.addMarkerGraphic(Double.parseDouble(friendData.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(friendData.getLongitude()), friendData.getFriendName(), friendData.getStatus(), null, icon, false,
                0);
```

This is my listener:

```
mvHelper.setOnGraphicClickListener(new OnGraphicClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGraphicClick(Graphic graphic) {
            Log.d("MVHELPER GRAPHIC LISTENER TAG",graphic.toString());
            calculateDirection((float)((Point)graphic.getGeometry()).getX(),(float)((Point)graphic.getGeometry()).getY());
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to get the lat long position of the clicked marker. But the listener doesn't provide it. So I tried the above way and got this error:

`com.esri.core.io.EsriServiceException:Unable to complete operation. Location "Location 2" in "Stops" is unlocated. Need atleast 2 valid stops. "Stops" does not contain valid input for any route.`

and this is the method where I get the route:

```
calculateDirection(float x, float y){
Log.d("Marker X and Y",String.format("%f // %f",x,y));
final Point loc = mapView.toMapPoint(x, y);
Log.d("Marker X and Y in MapPoint",String.format("%f // %f",loc.getX(),loc.getY()));
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                RouteParameters rp = mRouteTask
                        .retrieveDefaultRouteTaskParameters();
                NAFeaturesAsFeature rfaf = new NAFeaturesAsFeature();

                Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(loc, wm,
                        egs);
                Log.d("Marker X and Y after projection",String.format("%f // %f",p.getX(),p.getY()));
                StopGraphic point1 = new StopGraphic(mLocation);
                StopGraphic point2 = new StopGraphic(p);
                rfaf.setFeatures(new Graphic[] { point1, point2 });
                rfaf.setCompressedRequest(true);
                rp.setStops(rfaf);

                rp.setOutSpatialReference(wm);

                mResults = mRouteTask.solve(rp);
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mException = e;
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

}

**Update 1:**

After trying @jdONeill answer. I get the Lat and Long values.This is what I did.

```
Point temp = (Point)graphic.getGeometry();

Point p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(temp, wm,egs);
calculateDirection((float) p.getX(), (float) p.getY());
```

This is the result:

```
04-30 16:17:54.408  17908-17908/com.test.esrisample D/Marker X and Y﹕ -93.203285 // 44.881104
04-30 16:17:54.408  17908-17908/com.test.esrisample D/Marker X and Y in MapPoint﹕ -10379311.931913 // 5607101.545301
04-30 16:17:54.458  17908-17908/com.test.esrisample D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 484K, 22% free 10018K/12760K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
04-30 16:17:54.719  17908-18235/com.test.esrisample D/Marker X and Y after projection﹕ -93.238945 // 44.908331
```

Why is there a slight change in the latitude and longitude values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the geometry from the `Graphic` with `getGeometry()`.  If `Geometry.isPoint()` returns `true` you can get the X and Y coordinate of the point with `Point.getX()` & `Point.getY()` respectively.  To get a lat/lon you will need to ensure you have the correct projection.  Your route code uses the `GeometryEngine` to reproject the point so after your conversion you should have the lat/lon of the point graphic.

As to the exception you are getting, you must ensure the following:

- Both points are on a network to route
- Both points are in the same projection

From your code it looks like your Map is in **wm** but your stop point representing your graphic is in **egs**.

Comment: This helped. You are right. Once I projected the point which I get from the Graphic to egs I'm getting the lat long values. But still there is a slight difference between the original lat long position and the one received after projecting it in mapPoint. Please check the update in the question.